# Why are my horizontal photos scaling with screen size but my vertical photos are not?

Tags: html, css, mobile, photo, responsive

I am working on a site that has both vertical and horizontal photos that are on an overflow:scroll. On a desktop screen the photos look great and line up, However, when the screen size decreases (tablet or mobile) my landscape pictures scale great, my portrait photos stay the same size! Why?!

Edit: All photos are 300ppi

```css
     @media only screen and (max-device-width: 540px) {
     h1 {width: 100%;}
     }

     @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
     .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
     .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
     }



    .parent-container {
            width: 95%;

            height: auto;
         padding: auto;
            overflow: scroll;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            margin-top: 5px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            display: inline-block;

    }

    .container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;

    }

    .image {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding-right: 15px;
    object-fit: cover;

    }


    .parent-container .container .image {
    width: auto\9; /* IE8 */
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x500" alt="" class="image" 
    style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/323x485" alt="" class="image" 
    style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/323x485" alt="" class="image" 
    style="width:100%">
    </div>
 

     <div class="container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/323x485" alt="" class="image" 
     style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x500" alt="" class="image" 
     style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/323x485" alt="" class="image" 
     style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x500" alt="" class="image" 
     style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x500" alt="" class="image" 
     style="width:100%">
     </div>


     <div class="container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/323x485" alt="" class="image" 
     style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/323x485" alt="" class="image" 
     style="width:100%">
     </div>

     <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x500" alt="" class="image" 
    style="width:100%">
    </div>


    <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/323x485" alt="" class="image" 
    style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/323x485" alt="" class="image" 
    style="width:100%">
    </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: by horizontal/vertical, do you mean landscape/portrait?

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes I do.

Comment: How are we supposed to know which are portrait and which are landscape? And what are their resolutions? It would help if you recreated your layout using images from https://placeholder.com/

Comment: I have updated my question @MichaelCoker

Comment: Thanks. What exactly do you expect to happen? Do you want all images to be on the screen and scale down as you re-size? Or do you want a bunch of them to be off-screen as they are now? If so, at what point do you want landscape images to scale and stay in the viewport? I don't really understand what you're making and what the end goal is.

Comment: As you can see, I have several photos that scroll when you swipe or w/ a mouse/touchpad. When you change the screen size (as if on mobile or tablet) the landscape photos get smaller - great! However, the portrait photos stay the same exact size - not great! What I want is for those portrait shots to scale down just as the landscape photos did.

If I were to replace all the portrait shots with landscape shots everything would scale the same and there would be no awkward white space (I have done this for other pages). I want this look while using portrait shots. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, then please add 'img-responsive' class to img tag.

Comment: If I am not currently using bootstrap, is it easy to start?

Answer (score 0):

Please, the first thing you may do is to not use (never) inline style on your HTML (the style on the tags). You must apply width: 100% height: auto to your image, take a look at this example, I hope it will help you my friend: https://codepen.io/jorgemonte/pen/VpqmNN

```
.img-div{
 width: 100%;
}

.img-div img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
```

You can try not using the width: 100% for the image parent div, but it depends on what you need/want as a final result.

Comment: In your case, css must be:

.container{
width: 100%; (optional)
}

.container img{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

if it doesn't look well, depending on the image ration, try to invert and put the width: auto with the height: 100%.

Let me know if it worked well :)

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested except did auto for both width and height. My portrait shots did not scale as small as I wanted but I decided to vertical-align:middle so that there wasn't an awkward amount of white space. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome @KaylaC! Im glad it worked fine. Would you mind to give me a vote? Just by clicking on "this answer was useful". Thanks!